# How to include attributes of the MySQL table to hook_schema() schema in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, hooks, database

I am creating a table using [hook_schema()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7)

I am referring phpMyadmin to create a new table. In the phpMyadmin there is a
column `'Attributes'`

which has values as `'unsigned'` or  `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'`
I have a row in a table which is of type '`timestamp`' and has attributes 'on 
update `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'`.
How can I  include this attribute `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the `hook_schema()` ?

Also there is  a default column in phpMyAdmin how can I add that in `hook_schema()` ?

the first time I created a `hook_module_name.install` a table was created as it was specified in the `hook_schema()`

Then I uninstalled that module but the table was not deleted ?
Now I even removed the `.install` file cleared the cache , even after this  a table is not created. What can be the solution to this problem.

What I have checked is that it is entering into `hook_schema` function but the table is not generated at the database. Any hints on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello. Please avoid [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). I strongly suggest rollback and asking future questions using ["Ask Question"](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: ok. I am sorry..

Comment: No problem :) Keeping things clear and questions stable makes it easier to find answers, and more encouraging to answer - the only reason I mentioned it was to keep this site and community able and willing to provide what you need. You've read and applied, great. No reason to feel bad about mistakes that got corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an `ON UPDATE` unfortunately - Drupal's schema API doesn't give you that sort of dbms-specific control.

You can use `unsigned` for unsigned and `default` for a default value though:

```
$schema['some_table'] = array(
  'fields' => array(
    'some_field' => array(
      'type' => 'int',
      'not null' => TRUE,
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'default' => 0,
    ),
  ),
);
```

See the [Schema API docs](https://drupal.org/node/159605) for the full list of data types and usage.

Comment: pls check updated question? I am not able to generate or remove a table on enabling or disabling a module

Comment: I'd wager you didn't uninstall the module, and just disabled it. There's an 'uninstall' tab you need to visit once disabling the module (or run `drush pm-uninstall`)